# How can I shift and duplicate rows in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make a calculation in MS Access that uses the previous periods values. My approach is to make a second field for each variable that I am working with and to shift the table.

If my query qry1 is:

```
aa   bb   cc
---  ---  ---
12   34   56
78   91   01
```

My result should be:

```
aa0  bb0  cc0  aa1  bb1  cc1
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
12   34   56   NULL NULL NULL
78   91   01   12   34   56
NULL NULL NULL 78   91   01
```

I am encountering two problems:

1. I tried adding the empty rows on top and at the bottom in two extra queries and somehow rows get lost.
2. When I combine these two queries using JOIN I get a cartesian product, i.e. the rows are not side by side.

Comment: You must have a sortable unique key. If not, you cannot determine the "previous" record.

Comment: qry1 is sorted based on certain criteria, so would I need to add a key to both sides?

Comment: Not if these criteria are unique.

Comment: The simplest solution may be to loop the recordset from top to bottom in VBA using `MoveNext` where you store the current record's data before moving to the next record. ... Or simply to open a clone of the recordset, move this one record down and - from then on - move down both recordsets doing your calculations.

Comment: You should post your table structure and explain what 'periods' represent. Is the data entered via a form?

Comment: Could you post the SQL / VBA that you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use Ms Access like you would use Excel. It might be easier to do what you want using an Excel macro + formulae.

The power of access is that it is a SQL system (which is why you get a Cartesian product when you JOIN, that's the idea) it sounds like what you want could be done pretty easily with a flat spreadsheet. You could write VBA to add rows for you if want to automate that part.

If that doesn't help, then maybe describe in more detail what you actually want to accomplish.

EDIT:

I missed the part in your post where you said you were doing a calculation using previous values. This is how I would accomplish that within a single Access query:

```
qry_Data: (based on tbl_Data)

    id   aa   bb   cc   calc
    ---  ---  ---  ---  ---
    01   12   34   56   =Dlookup("aa","tbl_Data","id = " & [id] - 1)
    02   78   91   01   =Dlookup("aa","tbl_Data","id = " & [id] - 1)
```

You shouldn't add columns to your table as part of a normal operation. Access tables should be set up to hold all the data they will ever need to (until your model changes). If you are designing an operation in access and it seems like it should add columns, then you should be adding a linked table or using a calculated field. In the above example, the field calc will be equal to the value "aa" from the record with an ID# one less than the current record. This will only work if there is a record with that ID#, so if there is a possibility of there being a gap in ID numbers you shouldn't use this exact method. Since you said that the table is sorted on specific critiera you might need to use a different method to determine the previous record. One way to do that in VBA would be like this:

```
Dim RS as Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("myQuery")
RS.MoveLast
RS.MovePrevious
```

At that point you are on the second to last record and can access any values from that record with:

```
RS.Fields("aa")
```

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do I can't make any more specific recommendations except that if you familiarize yourself with basic SQL concepts and you will find working in Access much easier.

Comment: Thanks Henry, this pretty much describes it. The reason I wanted to go this path was to use some of my results from this table in another query. Staying in Access would have had a number of advantages, but this seems difficult to handle.

Comment: Well you have a couple of options. You can link an excel spreadsheet so that Access will use it as a table, and then do your shifting by using VBA to manipulate data in excel, but really it might be better to rethink how you are going about whatever it is you're trying to do.  You should think of an access table more like a set of records that contain certain data than like a spreadsheet. "Down" and "right" are only concepts that make sense when the data is being displayed in a datasheet and sorted in a particular order. The operation you described would be adding new fields to the table.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more ideas of how to do this.